# how to mock overload method in jest?

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm using jsonwebtoken library to validate tokens in my module. jsonwebtoken exports verify method more than one time (overloaded).

```
export function verify(token: string, secretOrPublicKey: Secret, options?: VerifyOptions): object | string;

export function verify(
    token: string,
    secretOrPublicKey: Secret | GetPublicKeyOrSecret,
    callback?: VerifyCallback,
): void;

export function verify(
    token: string,
    secretOrPublicKey: Secret | GetPublicKeyOrSecret,
    options?: VerifyOptions,
    callback?: VerifyCallback,
): void;
```

My module:

```
private validateToken(token: string): void {
        const publicKeyToPem = this.convertPublicKeyToPEM(this.ssoPublicKey);
        try {
            this.decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, publicKeyToPem);
        } catch (e) {
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    }
```

I tried to mock verify method in unit test.

```
    test('should return true if token is correct', () => {

        const verifyResponse = { 'test': 'test' };
        jest.spyOn(jwt, 'verify').mockReturnValue(verifyResponse);

        ........
    });
```

I get following error: Argument of type '{ test: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void'.ts(2345)
It seems last exported method (verify) is used and it returns void. 
I tried with `jest.spyOn(jwt, 'verify').mockImplementationOnce(() => verifyResponse);` it seems to be fine but how to mock specific overloaded method?

Comment: TypeScript doesn't seem to allow that. I personally resorted to a custom type assertion (eg, `jest.spyOn(jwt, 'verify').mockReturnValue(verifyResponse as any)`)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `jest.spyOn` you should use `jest.mock` like this

```js
const jwt = require('jwt-library');
const myMod = require('./myModule');

// it will replace all of the methods with jest.fn()
jest.mock('jwt-library')

describe('my module', () => {
  const mockDecodedToken = { 'test': 'test' };
  describe('calling a public method that calls validateToken', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      jwt.verify.mockReturnValue(mockDecodedToken);
      myMod.aPublicMethodThatCallsValidateToken()
    })

    it('should have called jwt.verify', () => {
      expect(jwt.verify).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        expect.any(String)
        expect.any(Secret)
        expect.any(VerifyOptions)
      )
    })

    it('should have assigned decodedToken to my module', () => {
      expect(myMod).toHaveProperty(decodedToken, mockDecodedToken)
    });
  })
})
```